# calculating probability of a kid have a sister

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, combinations

Suppose there is equal probability of Boy (B) and Girl (G). If a family has 3 kids, wondering what is the probability of a kid has a sister in the same family.

I have two methods of calculation, first method is a bit naive, and 2nd method is faster calculation, **and the question is for the 2nd method, I am not sure if under all scenarios the probability of two remaining kids are both boys could be calculated as 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4.** Thanks.

Method 1,

- G G G (1/8 probability have 3 boys in a family), in this condition,
  probability will be 1 for any kid to have a sister
- B B B (1/8 probability have 3 girls in a family) in this condition, probability
  will be 0 for any kid to have a sister
- G B B (3/8 probability have 2 boy2 and 1 girls in a family) in this condition, probability will be 2/3 for any kid to have a sister
- G G B (3/8 probability have 2 girls and 1 boy in a family) in this condition, probability will be 1 for any kid to have a sister

so probability of a kid having a sister is
1/8 + 0 + 1/4 + 3/8 = (1+2+3)/8 = 3/4

Method 2,

Suppose we select any kid in a family, and for the other two kids in the same family, the probability of two boys are 1/4 (when there is no sister scenario, **my question is whether the probability is correct calculate in this way, according to 4 scenarios of family**), so the probability of a kid having a sister is 1 - 1/4 = 3/4, the same result of method 1.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Both arguments look good to me.  You might be interested in [this more general question](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Probability/FamilyStats.shtml).

Comment: It's not unusual to find two or more different ways to arrive at the same result in Math, two or more different proofs of the same theorem, two or more different ways to think about the same concept,...

Comment: Thanks lulu for the reference and vote up. It is not exactly the same and it seems similar to my method 1. For the 2nd method, my confusion is, the 4 different types of B/G combination family have different distribution of boy and girl, and why does the universal way of calculation 1/2*1/2 as probability of two boys is correct in an universal way? It is obviously under specific scenarios, like G/B/B family, if we select any kids, the probability of the other two kids are boys should be 1/3 other than 1/4. Your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks Jim for the comments and vote up. If you could advise about my above question to lulu and joriki, it will be great. :)

Comment: BTW, lulu, read the family statistics document, and another confusion from me is, in the definition of combination, the subset selected should have unique elements, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination, but the subset like Boy Boy Girl is not unique since there are two Boy elements, and wondering how combination theory works here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods are fine. You didn't really specify the problem, but I gather you meant to imply that a child is selected from the family uniformly randomly, and that the genders of the three children are independent. In that case, both your arguments are correct.

Comment: Thanks joriki, yes, your understanding of the question and assumption is correct. Vote up for your reply. For the 2nd method, my confusion is, the 4 different types of B/G combination family have different distribution of boy and girl, and why does the universal way of calculation 1/2*1/2 as probability of two boys is correct in an universal way?

Comment: It is obviously under specific scenarios, like G/B/B family, if we select any kids, the probability of the other two kids are boys should be 1/3 other than 1/4. Your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: @LinMa: You're right that the conditional distribution given the overall composition of the family is different, but you didn't ask for the conditional probability but for the unconditional probability. I'm afraid I don't sufficiently understand your intuition that this unconditional probability should depend on the conditional probabilities to help dispel it :-)

Comment: Thanks joriki, vote up. For your comments, I think for "unconditional probability", you mean the probability of 2 remaining kids are both boys for all G/B combination of families? And for "conditional probability", I think you mean under a specific G/B combination of a family, what is the probability of 2 remaining kids are boy? If my understanding is correct for the terms you used, want to confirm you think the unconditional probability should or should not dependent on conditional probability? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa: Yes, that's roughly what I meant, though when you express it as "for all G/B combinations", that makes it sound again as if there were any connection to those combinations. The unconditional probability has no conditions at all, neither a specific G/B combination in the family, nor any other condition. An unconditional probability by definition doesn't depend on any conditions. The unconditional probability of rainfall tomorrow could be $\frac12$ and the conditional probability of rain given that the maximum temperature will be $3°C$ could be $\frac34$; there's no necessary connection.

Comment: Thanks joriki for the clarification and vote up, in this specific problem (what is the probability of a kid has a sister), in your mind it is unconditional problem or conditional problem? Or it could be both?

Comment: @LinMa: May I suggest that you read up on conditional probabilities? (E.g. at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).) There's no such thing as a conditional or unconditional problem. There are conditional and unconditional probabilities. You solved this problem once using conditional probabilities and once using an unconditional probability; both solutions are perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks joriki, vote up for your reply. Let me re-phrase for my question to make it clear, my confusion is on method 2 only. The unconditional probability of two kids are both boy is 1/4, so the unconditional probability of there is at least a girl is 3/4 -- there is no issue for me.

Comment: (cont'd) The real issue is, I think in method 2, there is a **pre-condition** (which is after a kid is selected) and it seems under a condition (conditional probability calculation) -- the question is, whether **under this condition (which is after a kid is selected)**, it is still true that the probability of two kids are both boy is 1/4 and why? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa: Yes, it's still true, because the three kids are independent and all have probability $\frac12$, so if you select any two of them uniformly randomly, you have two independent kids that each have probability $\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks joriki, it takes me 1-2 days to think about your comments further and learned a lot of stuff -- Thank you! Want to confirm my understanding is correct, you mean since the gender of 3 kids are independent, so after we independently select a kid, the gender distribution of the other two kids should not be impacted, so since the other two kids are independent for gender, the probability of both of them are boy should be 1/2 * 1/2, which is 1/4? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa: Yes, in a nutshell.

Comment: Thanks joriki for the patience to answer, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:** Using the Law of Total Probability.

Let $S$ be the event of selecting a child with a sister.  Let $F_{\rm GGG}, F_{\rm GGB}, F_{\rm GBB}, F_{\rm BBB}$ be the event of selecting a child from the relevant family structure; given that we know we are selecting from families with three children.

The count of girls in a family has a Binomial Distribution.   And for any given number of girls in a three child family, the probability of selecting a child with a sister is easily determined.   So, as you calculated for method 1. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(S) =&~ \mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm GGG})\mathsf P(F_{\rm GGG})+\mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm GGB})\mathsf P(F_{\rm GGB})+\mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm GBB})\mathsf P(F_{\rm GBB})+\mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm BBB})\mathsf P(F_{\rm BBB})\\[1ex]=&~ \mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm GGG})\cdot\tfrac 1 8+\mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm GGB})\cdot\tfrac 38+\mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm GBB})\cdot\tfrac 38+\mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm BBB})\cdot\tfrac 18\\[1ex]=&~ 1\cdot \tfrac 1 8 ~+~ 1\cdot\tfrac 38~+~\tfrac 2 3\cdot \tfrac 3 8~+~0\cdot \tfrac 18 \\[1ex]=&~ \tfrac 3 4\end{align}$$

**Method 2:**

The probability that at least one, of the two children that were not selected, was a girl is: $\mathsf P(S)=\tfrac 3 4$, as you determined using the law of complements.

---

To address you concerns.   $\mathsf P(S\mid F_{\rm GBB}) = \tfrac 23$ because in such a family the probability of selecting a child with a sister *is* the probability of selecting one of the two boys.   If you select a boy *from a family with two boys and one girl*, then he *will* have a sister, if you select the girl *from that family* then she will not.

And so on for the other family types, where fixing the number of girls among the three children *determines* how many children have a sister.   In a family with two or more girls, every child has a sister, and in a family with three boys, none will.

Where as when selecting a family (of three children) at random, there *isn't a fixed number of girls*, and so each child *independently* has a probability of $\tfrac 12$ for being a girl; and any child so selected has $\tfrac 34$ probability of having a sister.

Comment: Thanks Graham, excellent reply and vote up. I fully agree with you for the unconditional probability conclusion -- "The probability that at least one, of the two children that were not selected, was a girl is: (S)=3/4", the question and confusion is, in my specific problem, there is a pre-condition (**after select a child**), I am wondering if under this situation, whether the conclusion "The probability that at least one, of the two children that were not selected, was a girl" is still 3/4, and why? Thanks.